# Concatenating Multiple Columns in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, concat

I have the following data

```
JoinFlag    ReferenceType   ReferenceValue
A            CARRIER        Sample#######
A            LEASE_NUMBER       17438
A            LEASE_NUMBER       6054
A            STATION            ENERWST
B            LEASE_NUMBER       17704
B            LEASE_NUMBER       17711
B            STATION             RJ
B            STATION             C5
```

I would like to know how to write a SQL query in TSQL to get the following output

```
JoinFlag    ReferenceType   ReferenceValue
A            CARRIER        Sample#######
A            LEASE_NUMBER     17438, 6054
A            STATION          ENERWST
B            LEASE_NUMBER     17704, 17711
B            STATION          RJ, C5
```

The SQL should be generic.

The Query that I using is

```
SELECT [CustomTicketIgnoreList].JoinFlag,      
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ThisTable.ReferenceType
            FROM   [CustomTicketIgnoreList] ThisTable
            WHERE  [CustomTicketIgnoreList].JoinFlag = ThisTable.JoinFlag
            AND    ThisTable.ReferenceType <> ''
            FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS ConcatenatedSomeField, 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ReferenceValue
            FROM   [CustomTicketIgnoreList] ThisTable
            WHERE  [CustomTicketIgnoreList].JoinFlag = ThisTable.JoinFlag
            AND    ThisTable.ReferenceValue <> ''
            FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') AS ConcatenatedSomeField2
FROM [CustomTicketIgnoreList] 
GROUP BY JoinFlag
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it here: http://rextester.com/QQZWX40863

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (JoinFlag char(1), ReferenceType varchar(20), ReferenceValue varchar(50));
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES ('A','CARRIER','Sample#######');
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES ('A','LEASE_NUMBER','17438');
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES ('A','LEASE_NUMBER','6054');
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES ('A','STATION','ENERWST');
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES ('B','LEASE_NUMBER','17704');
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES ('B','LEASE_NUMBER','17711');
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES ('B','STATION','RJ');
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES ('B','STATION','C5');



SELECT DISTINCT 
    t2.JoinFlag, 
    t2.ReferenceType ,
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + ReferenceValue 
            FROM #t1
            WHERE #t1.JoinFlag = t2.JoinFlag and #t1.ReferenceType = t2.ReferenceType
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,''))
FROM 
   #t1 AS t2;
```